# Flask flash message before start long running function

Tags: python, flask

I have a Flask App which starts a long function after validation a form. I added a flash message before that function but the message appears after the function has finished:

```
# main_app.py
app = Flask(__name__)

class NameForm(FlaskForm):
    name = StringField('Email Adress', validators=[DataRequired()], default='test@gmail.com')
    # some more fields
    submit = SubmitField('Submit')

def run_my_long_task(name):
   # do some computing
   # save results to a file
   # return a pandas dataframe with the results for plotting with bokeh


@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    form = NameForm()
        if form.validate_on_submit():
        name = form.name.data
        # I want to display a message before the run starts
        flash('Analysis started, please wait.')
        # Start a time consuming analysis 
        run_my_long_task(name)
    
    return render_template('index.html', form=form)
```

Here is my index.html which contains a container with the flash message handling:

```
<div class="container">
{% for message in get_flashed_messages() %}
<div class="alert alert-warning">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>
    {{ message }}
</div>
{% endfor %}

{% block page_content %}{% endblock %}
```

The message shows up successfully but after the run_my_long_task() has finished. How to show up this message while the job is running?

**Edit:** So in general I just want to inform the user about the start of the analysis. Not necessarily need to be a flash message.

Comment: can you show your implementation of the `flash` function, please? It might be that you have returned a response in that flash function.

Comment: You need to remember that HTML is a one-in, one-out protocol.  You can't send intermediate results.  That means you're going to need to fire up a thread for your long-running task.  You'll have to include a short `time.sleep` to allow the request to complete.  Otherwise, the interpreter lock will not let the code continue.

Comment: The function return a pandas dataframe and stores a file. I updated my code.

Comment: @TimRoberts Ok I see, where to add time.sleep? Just after the flash()? I tried this before and behavior was the same.

Comment: Is the pandas rendering supposed to go to the browser?  If so, then you can't send an intermediate status messages.  You can't return until the whole response is ready.  To do what you're asking, you need to use AJAX.  Your web page has to be in control.

Comment: After the pandas dataframe is created, an html page with plots (bokeh) is created. I still don't fully understand why the message shows up after run_my_long_task() finished since I call the flash before the function call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up using [Bootstrap’s JavaScript modal plugin](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/), which is enough for my needs

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using the `flash` function on the server-side, you might want to use some javascript to achieve this:(this is just an example, so it might seem very ugly)

```html
<script>
document.querySelector('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    document.querySelector("#youform").addEventListener('submit', () => {
        const messageRef = document.querySelector("#flash-message");

        messageRef.innerHTML = 'the message';
        messageRef.styles.display = 'block';
        
    })
});
</script>

<div class="alert alert-warning" id="flash-message" style="display: hidden;">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>
    
</div>
```